# How to build images which are dynamically sourced by npm run build command in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, npm

I have some images inside src/assets/ and in one of my component
i have this

```
<img
          src="/src/assets/guna.jpg"
          alt="Guna"
          class="w-12 h-12 rounded-full"
        />
```

and also this :

```
<img
          :src="`src/assets/${image}`"
          alt=""
          class="w-12 h-12 rounded-full"
        />
```

**here i have bind image and passes image name in a loop and i have array of image in data which i loop in 
Now when i run npm run build , only top one image that is guna.jpg is buld and get copied in dist/assets/.......jpg but not images which are bind**
*so how i solve it ?*

Answer (score 0):

you have to use require

```
<img
      :src="require(`src/assets/${image}`)"
      alt=""
      class="w-12 h-12 rounded-full"
    />
```

Comment: Can i have a look at how you loop the image?

Comment: maybe you need to put ur image path into computed function so that it can keep ur image path updated and render it out when the page is created.